# Priority of operations in java /= operator

Tags: java, math, operators

I have the following the code in java, I understand what is the purpose of /=. 
My question is why the code is executing 4-1 first before the division.

```
int a = 20;
a /= 4-1;
```

If I wrote out `a = a/4-1;` I get 4, the above code gives 6.

Comment: Did you check first result for google query `java operator priority`  which is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html? Compare precedence of assignment vs additive operations. `a /= 4-1;` is same as `a /= (4-1);` which is `a=a/(4-1)` not `a=(a/4)-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the precedence if the assign operator "=" in Java. Let's rewrite it to make it clear:

```
int a = 20;
a /= 4-1;
```

could be:

```
int a = 20;
a     = a / (4-1);
```

and that's different from:

```
int a = 20;
a     = (a / 4) -1;
```

same is with "+=" if you think so:

```
int a = 20;
a     += 3*2;
```

here firs is:

```
int a = 20;
a     = a + 3*2;
```

and not:

```
int a = 20;
a     += (a + 3) *2;
```